# Why *finalize* operator not working when HTTP request finishes with code 500

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I have simple piece of code

```
this.httpService.create(this.entity) //Observable<Entity>
    .pipe(finalize(() => {
    console.log('finalizing');
    this.isLoading = false;
}))
.subscribe(entity=> {
     this.entity= entity;
     this.switchToNotFirstEdit();
},
console.error);
```

Why `finalize`is not called when HTTP request fails?

From `finalize` code comment

> Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, but will
>   call a specified function when  the source terminates on complete or
>   error.

So it should be called in my understanding

Comment: What does your method `this.httpService.create` returns? also code seems wrongly formatted

Comment: @PardeepJain its in comment `Observable<Entity>`

Comment: @PardeepJain ye you are right, it must be wrong formatting issue.